# error: disk 'lvmid/(uuid)' not found. Entering rescue mode…

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

I'm using an encrypted lvm system. I upgraded to xubuntu 22.04. The problem was, that my wi-fi card was not recognized. By trying to solve this problem I found that I couldn't upgrade to kernel 5.15 or higher. I was able to install new kernels but they wouldn't show in the grub menu. After some research a solution was offered to boot from a live usb and reinstall grub. I tried it but now I'm unable to enter grub menu and find myself in grub rescue. This is what I get:

```
error: disk 'lvmid'/(uuid)' not found.
Entering rescue mode…
grub rescue>_

#ls and set show:

grub rescue> ls
(hd0)

grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(lvmid/(uuid)/boot/grub
root=lvmid/(uuid)
```

(Normally I would get a prompt to decrypt the master-key and after successful decryption I would enter grub menu.)

My grub version is 2.04. (No cryptomount command.)

I booted via live usb and GParted shows:

```
/dev/sda1   ntfs   Windows   boot
/dev/sda2   ntfs     
/dev/sda3   extended
    /dev/sda5   encrypted
    /dev/sda6   ext4   grub
    /dev/sda7   encrypted
```

When decrypting both partitions it shows:

```
   /dev/sda5   ext4
   /dev/sda7   lvm2 pv   ubuntu-vg
```

When looking into sda5 it holds the files for grub menu. sda6 just holds the folder "grub" and is completely empty. (It feels to me that I have messed up stuff here while trying to reinstall grub.)

Question 1: How does this system normally work? Is sda6 first mounted/read and then the master-key prompt appears, and after entering the correct key sda5 is decrypted and the grub menu is displayed?

Question 2: How can I make this system work again?

Comment: I'm researching and looking into this problem for several days now, with no progress. Does anyone has a helpful suggestion or idea?